Can `rte_eth_tx_burst` frees buffer to external cache which could be configured during `rte_eth_tx_queue_setup`
Does DPDK support to free the transmitted buffers to external cache which is provided during tx queue configurations (rte_eth_tx_queue_setup).
This is needed to extract better performance when multiple tx queues are being worked on by unregistered non-eal pthreads which sends the packets (mbuf from common rte_mempool) to the queue parallelly using rte_eth_tx_burst. Otherwise, they are bypassed to go to the path of CAS operation on the common pool for free operation.
Or is there any other way to achieve this
Multiple unregistered non-eal worker threads doing tx operation in multi-process system.
I needed improved performance taking advantage of mempool cache (external) feature.
